# Overall ANOVA for Linear Models in R

Tags: r, regression, lm, anova, supernova

I can use the `anova` function to get the ANOVA table for linear model. However this gives the individual effects of each explanatory variable on the response variable. I wonder if there is any function in R to get the `overall ANOVA` where we can get the overall effect of all explanatory variables on response variable. Thanks in advance for your help.

### MWE

```
set.seed(12345)
X1 <- 10*abs(rnorm(n=10, mean = 5, sd = 1))
X2 <- 20*abs(rnorm(n=10, mean = 4, sd = 2))
Y <- 50*abs(rnorm(n=10, mean = 10, sd = 4))

df <- data.frame(X1, X2, Y)

fm1 <- lm(formula=Y~X1+X2, data=df)
anova(fm1)

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
X1         1  37842   37842  0.7815  0.406
X2         1 115774  115774  2.3910  0.166
Residuals  7 338941   48420
```

**Edited (2017-10-23)**

The required output is

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Y
           Df Sum Sq      Mean Sq      F value  Pr(>F)
Regression 2  153616.587  76808.293    1.586    0.2703
Residuals  7  338940.570  48420.081
```

Comment: have you looked at names(fm1)?  It lists all the parts to the anova, including effects.

Comment: How is overall ANOVA different from the F-statistic of the fit, which is given in `summary(fm1)`??

Comment: @jlhoward: Yes the overall ANOVA will give exactly the same F-statistic of the fit, which is given by `summary(fm1)`. I wonder if there is any `R` function to provide each component of overall ANOVA.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Your question isn't really clear to me if you're saying that summary(fm1) doesn't give you what you want.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this question?

Comment: @kputschko: Not yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`supernova` function from [supernova](/questions/tagged/supernova) package with option `type = 1` gives the required output.

```
library(supernova)
supernova(fm1, type = 1, verbose = FALSE)
Analysis of Variance Table (Type I SS)
 Model: Y ~ X1 + X2

                 SS df         MS     F    PRE     p
 ----- | ----------  - ---------- ----- ------ -----
 Model | 153616.587  2  76808.293 1.586 0.3119 .2703
 X1    |  37842.327  1  37842.327 0.782 0.1004 .4060
 X2    | 115774.260  1 115774.260 2.391 0.2546 .1660
 Error | 338940.570  7  48420.081                   
 ----- | ----------  - ---------- ----- ------ -----
 Total | 492557.157  9  54728.573
```

Answer (score 6):

OK let's try this: The F-statistic for the fit compares the fit to a fit with no predictors, e.g. the fit to `Y~1`. So

```
anova(lm(Y~1,df),lm(Y~X1+X2,df))
# Analysis of Variance Table
#
# Model 1: Y ~ 1
# Model 2: Y ~ X1 + X2
#   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
# 1      9 492557                           
# 2      7 338941  2    153617 1.5863 0.2703
```

gives you the components of the F-statistic of the fit:

```
summary(lm(Y~X1+X2,df))$fstatistic
#   value   numdf   dendf 
# 1.58629 2.00000 7.00000
```